# What is the total number of subgraphs of size n in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have a graph $G = (V, E)$ and I would like to know the total number of existing induced connected subgraphs of a given size $n$ (number of nodes).

By connected subgraph I mean any graph $G' = (V', E')$ such that  $V' \subseteq V$ and $E' \subseteq E$ and that there exist at least one path between every pair of nodes of $V'$.

By induced I mean that for example if my graph is a triangle $a$--$b$--$c$--$a$ and I consider the subgraphs of size $3$, I want to retrieve the whole triangle once, and not the included subgraphs $a$--$b$--$c$, $b$--$c$--$a$, $c$--$a$--$b$.

Comment: Here size means the number of vertices or the edges?

Comment: Is there anything more known about $G$? Counting connected subgraphs of a graph is known to be a difficult problem in computer science; see [this discussion](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3465/complexity-of-counting-all-connected-subgraphs) on cstheory.se.

Comment: n is the number of vertices.
I am interested for any type of graph G. I use graphs to model social networks but I don't think it is relevant for the question

Answer (score 1):

There is no known practical way to do this, absent extremely strong assumptions about $G$, even for moderate $N$. For example, if $G$ contains a clique of size $N$ then there are $2^\frac{N^2-N}{2}$ connected subgraphs whose vertices fall in that clique. When $N=10$, this gives $35,184,372,088,832$. If your graph contains an $11$ vertex clique, then adding that one extra vertex to the set of possible vertices in the subgraph gives $387,028,092,977,152$ graphs with $N=10$. And again, we haven't looked at the entire graph, just a clique of size $11$.

Comment: I want to compute the number of induced subgraphs, so if there is a clique of size N, I just want to take into account the clique itself and not all the other possible subgraphs contained in that clique.

Comment: @Alexis Pister,
You have some confusion with the notion of an induced subgraph.
Usually it is defined like this.
An induced subgraph of $G$ is obtained by taking a subset $U$ of $V(G)$
together with all edges which are incident in $G$ only with vertices
belonging to $U$.

Perhaps you should clarify your question.